# Suggestions on how to use SQLiteDatabase wisely for Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I'm thinking of making an app that involves, using a bit of data that is not too large, putting it into an SQLiteDatabase and doing simple operations with the data such as put them into a ListView or display a certain piece of data etc...

So I don't really know that best way of doing this so I've got a few questions to ask.

1. Is it wise to store my data in a file in my assets folder then extract the data from the file and put it into the SQLiteDatabase?
2. Is it better to just have the data hard-coded into execute statements when I create my Database?
3. Should I be using an AsyncTask to populate my SQLiteDatabase with the data I have?
4. If question 3 is yes, how do I run my Activity such that if I were to simply display the data in my database (in a textview), that the method I call from my Database class that helps me display the data, does so only when the database has been populated (when the AsyncTask has finished).

I hope these questions are clear enough!

Comment: You know your application requirements better than anyone else.  If the requirements aren't yet clear, try writing them down.  For example, what load time do you consider reasonable.  How often will the initial data change?  Is the data locale specific?  Etc.  Then, make a choice and, if you have trouble implementing, ask specific questions about that aspect.  This forum is really not a good place to ask and discuss subjective design issues.

Answer (score 0):

Both 1 & 2 approaches work flawlessly.
If you want to take approach #1 I really really recommend using [Jeff Gifelt's Sqllite asset helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). I found quite easy generating a sqllite db outside the app and embedding it.

Generally speaking, the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)'s onCreate method is created the first time you try to read / write to your db, which is something you always should be doing in another thread. The doc says:

> The database is not actually created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() is called.

So the answer is: you should not bother about when the db is created, what you should care about is reading / writing to it from a background thread / asynctask.